# how to remove objects from canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Is it possible to remove objects from a canvas? I know there's a function clearRect that sets the area specified to transparent. But I'm looking for a way to just remove an object.

For example say I have two rectangles 

`new Rect(100,100,110,110)

new Rect(90,90,105,105)`

the two circles overlap. If I use clearRect, removing one circle will remove a part of the other circle.

Any way of clearing one rect without clearing a part of the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove an object from the canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535914/how-to-remove-an-object-from-the-canvas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas is just a canvas to draw objects on, you have to manage objs on your own. Clear canvas, remove obj from obj list, redraw remaining objs.